# How to passing parameter to constructor when Resolve a View..?

Tags: c#, silverlight, silverlight-4.0, prism-2

my View constructor:

```
public View1(IRegionManager regionManager, IUnityContainer container, bool myParam)
{
}
```

How to set `myParam` when I do `Resolve<View1>()`? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to register the type with Unity and specify all the arguments:

```
this.container.RegisterType<View1>(new InjectionConstructor(this.container.Resolve<IRegionManager>(), this.container,true));
```

Then it'll know how to resolve it. Kind of defeats the purpose a little, which is why you may be better off setting the bool value as a property, and using `InjectionProperty` instead.

Comment: I tried with RegisterType but still no luck. Thank you, now I'm using interface and property to set the variable.